# How to cut off timestamp from date in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The current data in the s_date column `2018-05-04 00:00:00`

I want to it display in the format of 4/5/2018

Below is my script in Postgresql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_namewhere CAST(s_date AS VARCHAR) LIKE '%2018%'
```

Comment: In the query you are checking for 2018 records. Do you want that or you just want to display the date in format of 4/5/2018

Comment: yea, I want to display the format from all data with date in 2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `s_date` is defined as `timestamp` or `date`, you can use [to_char()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

```
select to_char(s_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as formatted_date
from the_table;
```